# German characters problem

Tags: pdftex, characters, german

My LaTeX document does not properly represent German character. In my opinion, I have my preamble set correctly. what needs to be set correctly, so that the characters such as Ä, ß, etc. are represented?

My preamble:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nomencl}
```

and the document settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,ngerman,intoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,BCOR10mm,captions=tableheading,titlepage,fleqn]{scrbook}
```

Comment: without any example of your input or output or error messages it will be difficult to help. Are you sure your file is latin-9 encoded rather than,say, utf-8 ?

Comment: Echoing David's comment, it could well be that your document's input encoding is `utf8` rather than `latin1`. Change the argument of the `inputenc` package and try to recompile your document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pdflatex` the following code produces the correct characters, if the file is saved as `utf-8`.
To check this, open up the "save" menu and look an option like `encoding`(auf Deutsch wahrscheinlich `Textcodierung` oder sowas). If you use a editor, that is more `LaTeX`-specific, you may find general encoding settings somewhere else. We can help you with this, but we need to know which software you are using.

Maybe it is possible to get this to work with `latin9` as well, but there is no point to do so, because `utf-8` is far superior. By the way: It's possible to use *every* UTF character there is in your code, if you switch from `pdflatex` to `xelatex` or `lualatex` (... at least if you have a font, that has a glyph for this character).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,ngerman,intoc,bibliography=totoc,index=totoc,BCOR10mm,captions=tableheading,titlepage,fleqn]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\begin{document}
Umlaute: Füße, Räder und Böden.
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @Ramosta If you are using xelatex remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (the file has to be utf-8 encoded and `inputrnc does nothing useful)

Comment: `xelatex` or `laualatex` require some differences in the preamble, for example the `fontspec` package replaces `fontenc` and `inputenc`, also `babel` should be replaced by `polyglossia`. Since you are german, have a look at our latex slides from the workshop we did. It's a rather complete overview over latex and we use lualatex:
http://toolbox.pep-dortmund.de/notes.html